# Identifying two Marvel characters

Tags: harry-potter, marvel, character-identification

There were two Marvel characters mentioned in a Harry Potter/Marvel crossover fic, who I am unable to identify. Any idea?

> The broad shouldered man smiled down at Dumbledore. "**I am Merlyn's
> representative in this reality little wizard. My mission is to
> justice**, not your nebulous 'greater good'. You lack the power to
> remove me, as your amusing wards told you when we arrived.

> Merlyn really doesn't like you or what your people have been doing with his heritage" the bare footed woman said. "Now that I've met you, I can understand why the land here is so unhappy.

The only meaningful pieces of information I have to identify them outside of the above quotes:

- Their names: Brian and Megan (or Meggan, the fic clearly needs editing as there were both versions on the same page)
- They are familiar with or associated with either Iron Man and/or Agatha Harkness

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Brian Braddock](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/captain-britain/4005-7477/) (AKA Captain Britain, AKA Captain Avalon) was a companion of Merlin's in various Marvel comics including *[Excalibur](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/excalibur/4050-4052/)*

[image]

His wife, [Meggan](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/meggan/4005-7604/) (AKA Meggan the Witch) was also companion of Merlin's

[image]